# How to create an autonomous GO for Wifi Direct in Android with dedicated ssid and passphrase?

Tags: android, wifi

I am trying to create a WI-FI Direct network with say 3 tablet PCs. I want to run WiFi-Direct as background service, with one device set as autonomous GO. Could someone please tell me how can this be done in Android? Also someone please tell me how we can set dedicated SSID and passphrase so that any time new devices are added to this network, they can search for a specific ssid and passphrase for connection establishment during the application initiation ?

I am using Android API Level 18 for my development ...

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Someone please help answering this question. Even I would like to know how can this be done ... I am trying to create persistent wifi direct group in android when i have a device which will always be group owner. I am trying to create a p2p group with 5 devices with one device always as group owner. For first time, i could create a group, but in subsequent connections, I would like to have the group be formed with available devices and previous group owner as current group owner. How can we do this in android ? Please help ...

Answer (score 6):

This is how an autonomous Group Owner is created i.e. using the following code you can deliberately set a device in **Wifi direct Network as a Group Owner**

```
manager.createGroup(channel,new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onSuccess()
    {
        Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Group Created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int reason)
    {}              
});
```

You can use this code on any event like Button click etc.

Answer (score 2):

Bluemoon10 was almost right. I can't comment yet because I need 50 reputation :/. The config.groupOwnerIntent ranges from 1-15 with 15 being the highest intent to be group owner.
If 2 devices try to connect with both GO intents == 15, the connect call will fail. If there is a GO intent tie lower than 15, the devices agree on a tie breaker bit and will succeed. So if you want one device to be group owner, you have to make sure that it is the only one trying to be. You can do this with Service Discovery, i.e. if there is a service running set your GO intent to 15 on the device with the service and 1 on the connecting device. Only one device needs to call connect to initiate connection.

Link to Service Discovery tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html

Answer (score 2):

To create autonomous group you can just invoke `createGroup()` method from your manager. In order to set **ssid** and **passPhrase** you must invoke the hidden methods of WifiP2pGroup class **setPassphrase** and **setNetworkName**.

To achieve that, you use java reflection. Try the following example.

Let us assume `WifiP2pGroup` group your current object.

Method

```
setPassPhraseMethod=group.getClass().getMethod("setPassphrase", new Class[ {String.class});
```

and now you invoke the method:

```
setPassPhraseMethod.invoke(group, "yourNewPassPrhase");
```

hope it is helpful.

Comment: Examining the source and testing it myself, this will change the internal members, but it will not have any effect on the group itself.

Comment: @Jared what was the result of testing this?

Comment: Well if you have root you can do this on some of the devices, see here: https://github.com/Mygod/VPNHotspot/blob/2.3.0/mobile/src/main/java/be/mygod/vpnhotspot/net/wifi/P2pSupplicantConfiguration.kt

Answer (score 0):

Normally the Group Owner is decided by the WiFi Direct protocol.
However you can force it's hand by, using the config class.

```
final WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
                    config.deviceAddress=myDeviceAddr;
                    config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
                    config.groupOwnerIntent =15;
```

In this case I think I'm correct in saying that 15 mean least likely to become GO, you set this to zero, if you want that device to be the GO.
Also this might be where you can set pin etc take a look at WpsInfo.
this config info in then passed into your connect call.

```
mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener().
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: your response is almost correct. But 0 is least likely to became GO and 15 the most.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pConfig.html#groupOwnerIntent